Find shortest subarrays A[0:L], B[0:L] where M different elements in A are bigger than M different elements in B (time complexity)
I need to find minimum subarray of size L, A[0:L], B[0:L] such that there are M different elements in A that are bigger than M different elements in B. Like A[i] > B[j] counts but I cannot use A[i] or B[j] again. Also subarrays must start from the beginning of array.
The homework is about AVLTrees and Heap so I guess a solution would involve one of them (For the example below, I used the priority_queue from stl but actually I am not allowed to use any container from any library so I already have min-heap implementation but for easy-understanding I used the stl equivalent). Also I am expected to solve the question using AVL Tree or Heap.
Ps. I have found out that arrays can contain duplicate elements.
The size of A and B are the same which is: N.
I need to find a solution that has time complexity O(N * logN * logM)
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <span>

int minLenOfSubarrays(std::span<int> aArr, std::span<int> bArr, int M)
{
    const int N = aArr.size();
    int count = 0;
    int L = 0;

    int left = M;
    int right = N;
    while(left <= right){ //log N
        //Heap a; //min-heap
        //Heap b; //min-heap
        int mid = left+(right-left)/2;
        std::priority_queue<int,std::vector<int>,std::greater<int>> a;
        std::priority_queue<int,std::vector<int>,std::greater<int>> b;
        count = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < mid; j++){ //N log N
            a.push(aArr[j]);
            b.push(bArr[j]);
        }
        while(!a.empty()){ // N log N
            if(a.top() > b.top()){
                count++;
                a.pop();
                b.pop();
            }
            else{
                a.pop();
            }
        }
        if(count >= M){
            L = mid;
            right = mid-1;
        }
        else{
            left = mid+1;
        }
    }
    return L;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int aArr[] = {2,4,10,6,1,11};
    int bArr[] = {3,5,8,9,7,12};
    int M = 3;
    
    std::cout << minLenOfSubbarays(aArr, bArr, M) << '\n';
}

I have tried a solution using min-heaps and binary search but the complexity that I could reach is max O(N*logN*logN).

Try using pointers instead of using auxiliary containers.  Copying elements takes execution time.

@ThomasMatthews The elements are just ints. How does using pointers make this faster?

What is your question about this assignment? I find questions on SO(stackoverflow)/SE to work best when there is one explict answerable question near the end of a question post.

With pointers, you don't need separate arrays, just use separate pointers.

@ThomasMatthews What separate arrays do you mean?

There are separate vectors, a and b.

@ThomasMatthews But they're not just vectors. They're priority queues. The insertions don't just "copy" the elements, they reorder them as needed by the priority queue. How do you do that with your pointers?

In your binary search, for each mid do this:

Compute the M largest values in A[0:mid], in ascending order. Can be done in O(mid * logM) with an AVL tree or a heap of size M. Which is also O(N * logM).
Compute the M smallest values in B[0:mid], in ascending order. Again O(N * logM).
Go through them in parallel, checking whether each A-value is larger than the B-value. Takes O(M), which is also O(N).

The binary search contributes the remaining factor logN.
Bonus: You can make it O(N * logN) by sorting all A-values and all B-values before the binary search and then for each mid you get the above A-values and B-values of steps 1 and 2 by instead filtering those already sorted values. In "executable pseudocode":
from bisect import bisect

A = 2,4,10,6,1,11
B = 3,5,8,9,7,12
M = 3

# Sort indices by their values
N = len(A)
Ai = sorted(range(N), key=A.__getitem__)
Bi = sorted(range(N), key=B.__getitem__)

# Check whether A[:L] and B[:L] have the desired property 
def enough(L):
    largeA = [A[i] for i in Ai if i < L][-M:]
    smallB = [B[i] for i in Bi if i < L][:M]
    return all(a > b for a, b in zip(largeA, smallB))

# Binary search, find the smallest L from M to N that's enough
L = bisect(range(N), False, M, N, key=enough)
print(L)

(This assumes there always is a valid L, otherwise you would've specified what to do if not.)
Attempt This Online!
I think we can even achieve O(NlogM + MlogN). Still do the binary search, but don't start from scratch for each new mid. Instead just update a tree of the M largest A-values:

If mid is larger than previously, insert each new value and remove the smallest after each insertion. Similar for B.
If mid is smaller than previously, then undo the insertions/removals you did to get to the larger mid. So this requires keeping track of what updates you did, at least which elements were removed. It's clear which elements got inserted.

Overall you have O(N) single-value updates, each costing O(logM). And you have O(logN) binary search rounds, each costing O(M) for comparing the M pairs. (This might be inspired by Costantino's answer.)

Thanks for your answer but what happens to duplicate numbers in this situation?

@Mert What about them?

I believe AVL works on unique keys and for Heaps i believe getting the M maximum elements for A is easy because we can remove the top element when we encounter a bigger element than the top in a min-heap but i dont know how to get the minimum elements for B because if i use a maxheap for similar strategy then i’ll lose access to smallest element in B.

@Mert If your AVL tree doesn't support duplicates, you can make them unique by attaching their index or so. For example, if you have the value 17 at indices 3 and 8, they become (17,3) and (17,8). For the heap for B, indeed use a max-heap to find the M smallest elements. At the end, just sort them in O(M * logM) before comparing them with the A-elements. (One way to do that is to do the second part of heap sort.)

I just modified my AVL tree so it can support duplicates, Thus, i believe it now works fine with the desired complexity.

if mid [gets smaller,] undo nah. Just keep the previous set when going right to return to when that proves too far. With M << N, use exponential search.

@greybeard Hmm, yeah, that should work as well. Costs O(M) time to make a copy, but we spent that much for the "all >" check anyway.

#include <iostream>
#include "AVLTree.h"
bool canSatisfy(int N, int M, int* aArr, int* bArr){
    AVLTree a;
    AVLTree b;

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){ // N*logM
        a.insertKey(aArr[i]);
        if(a.getSize() > M){
            a.removeKey(a.getMin());
        }
        b.insertKey(bArr[i]);
        if(b.getSize() > M){
            b.removeKey(b.getMax());
        }
    }
    int count = 0;
    while(a.getSize() != 0 && b.getSize() != 0){
        if(a.getMin() <= b.getMin()){
            return false;
        }
        a.removeKey(a.getMin());
        b.removeKey(b.getMin());
    }
    //total N*logM
    return true;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int aArr[] = {2,4,10,3,6,9,12,1,11,13,11,20};
    int bArr[] = {3,11,5,8,18,12,9,14,13,7,2,12};
    int N = 12;
    int M = 6;
    int L = 0;

    int left = M;
    int right = N;

    while(left <= right){ //Binary search logN
        int mid = left+((right-left)/2);
        if(canSatisfy(mid,M,aArr,bArr)){ // canSatisfy = N*logM
            L = mid;
            right = mid-1;
        }
        else{
            left = mid+1;
        }
    }
    //total O(N*logN*logM)
    std::cout << L << std::endl;
}

I think this solution achieves the desired O(NlogNlogM) time complexity. Thanks to the suggestions from @nocomment

Edit: this is worse than the original proposal... sigh.
I'm not a computational complexity expert, but the idea of rebuilding a data structure every time feels bad. Given that everybody wants to avoid copying data around, I don't think it's ok to rebuild everything from scratch every time.
So my try is to just incrementally build two sorted sequences (every insert costs log2 of the number of elements already inserted) and then read in-order from them to get the count of how many elements of aArr are greater than distinct ones from bArr.
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
#include <set>

int minLenOfSubarrays(std::span<int> aArr, std::span<int> bArr, int M)
{
    std::multiset<int> a{ begin(aArr), begin(aArr) + M - 1 };
    std::multiset<int> b{ begin(bArr), begin(bArr) + M - 1 };
    for (int L = M - 1; L < int(aArr.size()); ++L) {
        a.insert(aArr[L]);
        b.insert(bArr[L]);
        auto it = begin(b);
        int count = 0;
        for (const auto& x : a) {
            if (x > *it) {
                ++it;
                ++count;
            }
        }
        if (count >= M) {
            return L + 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    {
        int aArr[] = { 2,4,10,6,1,11 };
        int bArr[] = { 3,5,8,9,7,12 };
        std::cout << minLenOfSubarrays(aArr, bArr, 3) << '\n';
    }
    {
        int aArr[] = { 2,4,10,6,1,11 };
        int bArr[] = { 3,5,8,1,9,7 };
        std::cout << minLenOfSubarrays(aArr, bArr, 4) << '\n';
    }
    {
        int aArr[] = { 2,4,10,6,1,11 };
        int bArr[] = { 3,5,8,1,9,12 };
        std::cout << minLenOfSubarrays(aArr, bArr, 6) << '\n';
    }
}

I chose to output 0 in case we cannot get the required M, even by using all of the arrays.
Sets are usually implemented with RB-trees, which I think fit your task.
Probably you should switch from int to size_t for the return value, since it's a number of elements. What if you have more than 2³¹-1 elements? (StackOverflow should definitely allow KaTeX markup).
Side note
Honestly, while I get how to implement this with a tree in which every node has two pointers to the children and an additional pointer to the parent, I'm not sure I'd be able to do it without the pointer to parent (for iterating on b). Should I use a stack? Can this be done with recursive calls? No idea!

@greybeard I mean mathematic stuff. In this case something for 2^31.

Why the down vote? This uses trees and is definitely better than the OP original try. Moreover it's not a direct answer, since this has to be modified before submitting to the instructor (no STL data structures).

I mean the Javascript version of Latex for the web: https://katex.org/

I think in A = 1, 1, 1, 1, 1; B = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; M = 3 the result is 3: A[1] > B[0], A[2] > B[2], A[0] > B[1] - no re-use A[i] or B[j].

With the premise that I'm no expert in complexity, it looks just a special case. If the vector is already sorted, also QuickSort is doing a lot of useless work.

@greybeard Thinking again, you're right. L should start from M, because it's impossible to have M elements of a larger than those in b if  we don't even have M elements!

@greybeard Sorry, now I get the problem. The fact is that I understood "M different values". So, we can solve it by allowing duplicates in the set, by using a multiset.

You replaced their binary search with a linear search. This is not better. It's worse.

@nocomment You're right: the computational complexity is worse. I was distracted by the constant rebuilding of two heaps. Constantly copying the data will cost a lot, but less than the worse computational complexity. Tested with 100000 elements arrays and M=50000 (with L=50081, so not so bad for the linear search). The result is clearly in favor of the original version.

I think unsuccessful approaches executed properly helpful.

@greybeard Thank you for the moral support. I still feel a little ashamed .

You could try what I just sketched in my answer's last paragraph. A mix of binary search and updating instead of starting from scratch.

I did not (yet) find a way to not "brute force" this to some degree when L much smaller N.

Start with (balanced where that helps) search trees X and Y for the first k = M elements in A and B.

check done:
iterate X and Y in order comparing the X/A element to the corresponding one from Y/B: when all are greater, terminate with L = k.
Otherwise let x and y be the offending values.

process next pair:

let from1 = false and increment k by one

let X represent the M largest elements among the first k elements in A: if the kth element r in A is no greater than the smallest element in X, X doesn't need to change. Otherwise, X needs to include r dropping the smallest.
If y < r, from1 = true

Symmetrically process the kth element from B (Y being the M smallest elements).

If from1, repeat from 1, else 2.




If L is not guaranteed to exist, that needs to be handled first in step 2.
One could prune pairs where the value from A is exactly one greater than the one from B.
The brute force step is step 1., not taking advantage of the previous check.

irritatingly, the easy upper bound is LM ((L-M)M + LlogM), making this inferior to "the binary search for L establishing M extremal values from prefixes of A and B of length k from scratch" unless LM is small.
